# Why can't I match using package name in /etc/apt/preferences?

Tags: apt, package-management, pinning

I'm trying to pin some packages from the google chrome repo. I can't figure out why I can't pin packages by name. When I run apt-cache policy google-chrome-beta I observe that the first of the following cases does not match the package (but I expect it should) while the second does (as I expect).

```
 # doesn't match (apt-cache policy google-chrome-beta)
 Package: google-chrome-beta
 Pin: origin "dl.google.com"
 Pin-Priority: 50

 # does match
 Package: *
 Pin: origin "dl.google.com"
 Pin-Priority: 50
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do you just want to prevent google-chrome-beta from being updated?

Comment: Yes, but I don't want to use holds and I also want to prevent installation of all other packages from that origin.

Comment: Then why not comment out the relevant ppa in software sources?

Comment: Because I do want two of the packages from that origin.

Comment: I'm really confused. Why do you not want to use `hold`? Are you trying to have stable, beta, and unstable all installed at the same time but selectively upgrade one (or some of them)? Why don't you explain clearly by editing the question to provide exactly what you want to do?